# Evitar el ingreso de datos según condiciones del programa en ejecución

Tags: c++

Se trata de hacer una tragaperras simple y solo me falta una cosa que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo: el programa no me permita ingresar mas fichas mientras estoy jugando.

```
while(true){{
        if(kbhit()) {{
            int tecla=getch();
            switch(tecla){{
            case 'z':
                cout<<"Cuantas fichas quiere inresar?"<<endl<<endl;
                cin>>fichasin;
                fichas = fichas + fichasin;
                cout<<"Usted ahora tiene "<<fichas<<" fichas"<<endl<<endl;
                break;
            case 'x':{
                if ((fichas > 0) && (fichasden>0)){
                    srand(time(NULL));
                    ran1 = rand()%8;
                    ran2 = rand()%8;
                    ran3 = rand()%8;
                    cout<<ran1<<ran2<<ran3<<endl<<endl;
                    fichas--;
                    cout<<"Ahora tiene "<<fichas<<" fichas"<<endl<<endl;
                        cout<<"Precione X para seguir jugando"<<endl<<endl;
                        cout<<"Precione C para dejar de jugar"<<endl<<endl;
                    if ((ran1==ran2) && (ran1==ran3)){{
                        cout<<"Usted gano "<<ran1+ran2+ran3<<" fichas"<<endl<<endl;
                        fichas = (fichas + ran1+ran2+ran3);
                        fichasden - (ran1+ran2+ran3);
                        cout<<"Ahora tiene "<<fichas<<" fichas"<<endl<<endl;
                    }}}else 
                    cout<<"Usted no tiene fichas"<<endl<<endl;
                break;
            case 'c':
                cout<<"Usted tiene "<<fichas<<" fichas, gracias por jugar."<<endl<<endl;
                exit(1);}}}}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo colocar un booleano que sea verdadero mientras estés jugando, con esa condición validas el ingreso o no de más fichas.

Comment: Pero que rayos estas haciendo con los `{}`? Porque tienes if que empiezan `{{`?

Comment: @JeanGotopo    Lo lamento pero no entiendo, estoy viendo todo el material que hemos dado hasta ahora y aun no hemos usado boleados en la clase, cuando digo que empece a estudiar lo digo como que este es el primer mes y apenas se cosas. Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo? No creo que los profesores nos hagan hacerlo de una forma que aun no hemos visto.

Comment: Es mejor poner el `srand(time(NULL));` al comenzado del programa para ejecutarlo una vez solo.

Comment: @Facundo, booleano es un tipo de dato que devuelve un valor verdadero o falso; supongo que ya viste el tema de tipos de datos es uno de los primeros temas que se ve en fundamentos de programación. Puedes revisar la siguiente página: https://www.zator.com/Cpp/E3_2_1b.htm